# Overline over a whitespace

Tags: logic

I'm defining a boolean algebra in latex and I need to overline a whitespace to introduce the NOT operator.

This is the latex code I used

```
$$\mathcal{A} = (\mathcal{B},+,\cdot, \overline{ })$$
```

The problem is that instead of showing an overlined whitespace it shows nothing, as if there was no overline.

EDIT: I've just tried replacing `\overline{}` with `\overline{\ }` and 
an overlined has appeared, but it is not at the right height. It seams more like an underscore than an overscore.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: `\overline{\phantom{x}}`

Comment: Try  $\overline{\phantom{x}}$ and see whether it befits you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Please write it down in the answers section so I can close the question.

Comment: @egreg ^^^ You have mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\overline{<text>}` you get an overline adjusted both for the width and the height of the `<text>`. So `\overline{}` yields nothing, but `\overline{\ }` puts the overline over an item that has no height.

Using `\overline{\phantom{x}}` you overcome both problems.

A comparison:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
\verb|\overline{}| & $x\overline{}x$ \\
\verb|\overline{\ }| & $x\overline{\ }x$ \\
\verb|\overline{\phantom{x}}| & $x\overline{\phantom{x}}x$ \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, it's better if you define a command, for instance

```
\newcommand{\overblank}{\overline{\phantom{x}}}
```